# Norm of functional on $C[-1,1]$ defined as $P(f) = f(1)+f(-1)-2f(0)$

Tags: functional-analysis

I am studying for my final exam and kinda struggling with the following:

> Calculate the norm of functional on $C[-1,1]$ defined as $P(f) = f(1)+f(-1)-2f(0)$

This seems like one-liner but I am clueless anyway. I appreciate your time.

Comment: What norm are you using on $\mathcal C([-1,1])$?

Comment: Standard norm(supremum).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly

$$\vert P(f) \vert \le 4 \Vert f \Vert_\infty.$$ So the norm of $P$ is less or equal to $4$. Now $f(x) = -\cos \pi x$ is such that

$$f(0) = -f(1)=-f(-1)=-1$$ and $ \Vert f \Vert_\infty =1$. So $\vert P(f) \vert = 4$ and $\Vert P \Vert = 4$.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $\|P\| \le 4$. Let $f(x) = 2x^2-1$. Then
$$f(1) = f(-1) = 1, \quad f(0) = -1$$
so $P(f) = 4$. On the other hand, we have
$$\|f\|_\infty = \sup_{x\in[-1,1]}|f(x)| = \sup_{x\in[0,1]}(2x^2-1) =1$$
so we conclude $\|P\|=4$.